# How to fix and re-arrange fixed position divs

Tags: html, css, position

First of all, sorry for my title if it's misleading. Actually, I don't know the better title for this, that's why I gave it like this. If anyone can get a better title for this solution, please kindly help me to change.

My problem is that, one of my web developer created the page with div position fixed and placed all the div properly. Now the problem came in, I want to shift everything to the center of the browser. I tried to wrap with whole div and move to center. But it doesn't move because of position:fixed, aligning with left. I don't want to calculate every left position and move it, because it's too much. How can i just wrap whole thing and move it to center by better way? I included some codes to get idea what i am talking. If my question is not really helpful, please kindly let me know, I will explain more.

HTML

```
<div id="apDiv1"><img src="images/bg.png"  /></div>
<div id="apDiv2"><img src="images/border1.png"  /></div>
<div id="apDiv3"><img src="images/border2.png" width="130" height="450" /></div>
<div id="apDiv4"><img src="images/bar1.png" width="128" height="450" /></div>
<div id="apDiv5"><img src="images/bar2.jpg" width="110" height="164" /></div>
<div id="apDiv6"><img src="images/bar3.jpg" width="110" height="164" /></div>
<div id="apDiv7"><img src="images/button1.jpg" width="110" height="164" /></div>
<div id="apDiv8"><img src="images/button2.jpg" width="110" height="164" /></div>
<div id="apDiv9"><img src="images/button3.jpg" width="286" height="23" /></div>
<div id="apDiv10"><img src="images/redbar.jpg" width="286" height="23" /></div>
<div id="apDiv11"><img src="images/redbar.jpg" width="286" height="23" /></div>
<div id="apDiv12"><img src="images/redbar.jpg" width="286" height="23" /></div>
<div id="apDiv13"><img src="images/gobtn.png"  /></div>
<div id="apDiv14"><img src="images/submitbtn.png" /></div>
<div id="apDiv15"><img src="images/submitbtn3.png" /></div>
<div id="apDiv16"><img src="images/downloadbtn.png" /></div>
```

CSS

```
#apDiv1 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:-1;
    left:120px;
}

#apDiv2 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 380px;
    top: 108px;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 248px;
    top: 108px;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 120px;
    top: 108px;
}
#apDiv5 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 380px;
    top: 195px;
}
#apDiv6 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 677px;
    top: 196px;
}
#apDiv7 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 380px;
    top: 387px;
}
#apDiv8 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 677px;
    top: 387px;
}
#apDiv9 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 380px;
    top: 171px;
}
#apDiv10 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 677px;
    top: 171px;
}
#apDiv11 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 677px;
    top: 362px;
}
#apDiv12 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 380px;
    top: 362px;
}
#apDiv13 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 579px;
    top: 346px;
}
#apDiv14 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 875px;
    top: 346px;
}
#apDiv15 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 579px;
    top: 538px;
}
#apDiv16 {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 875px;
    top: 538px;
}
```

Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fixed position element is positioned relative to the browser window. It's not controlled by it's parent element. So you cannot wrap it with a a div and make it follow the position of your wrapper. You'll need to re-adjust the values of every fixed div if you want to change their positions. I don't see a reason why you would want to use fixed position on so many elements. Not a good practice.

Comment: yea, that's the other developer's work. So can i know what's the best way to using div when we creating the layout ? As a position absolute or relative ?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to make he wrapper div relative and all child divs absolute. That way the child divs will be positioned In respect to the wrapper and not the browser window. Going this route, will give the flexibility to re-postiion the wrapper and have everything inside it reposition accordingly.

Comment: so, if i will create wrapper div with position relative and change all those child divs to absolute inside relative, it will works right ?

Comment: thank you, it works, but have to change alot of things, no chioce :/ thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rearchitect the whole page you can use this Javascript (placed after all the divs) and just change the value of `moveLeft` to however many pixels you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var moveLeft = 100,
    elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    el = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < el; i++) {
    if (/apDiv/.test(elems[i].id)) {
        elems[i].style.left = (elems[i].offsetLeft - moveLeft) + 'px';
    }
}
</script>
```